# Using .size() vs const variable for loops

Tags: c++, vector, coding-style, constants

I have a `vector`:

```
vector<Body*> Bodies;
```

And it contains pointers to `Body` objects that I have defined.

I also have a `unsigned int const` that contains the number of `body`objects I wish to have in `bodies`.

```
unsigned int const NumParticles = 1000;
```

I have populated `Bodies`with `NumParticles` amount of `Body` objects.

Now if I wish to iterate through a loop, for example invoking each of the `Body`'s Update() functions in `Bodies`, I have two choices on what I can do:

First:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NumParticles; i++)
{
    Bodies.at(i)->Update();
}
```

Or second:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Bodies.size(); i++)
{
    Bodies.at(i)->Update();
}
```

There are pro's and con's of each. I would like to know which one (if either) would be the better practice, in terms of safety, readability and convention.

Comment: _"I would like to know which one (if either) would be the better practice, in terms of safety, readability and convention."_ `Bodies.size()` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the `.size()` function instead of defining a new constant.

Why?

1. Safety : Since `.size()` does not throw any exceptions, it is perfectly safe to use `.size()`.
2. Readability : IMHO, `Bodies.size()` conveys the size of the vector `Bodies` more clearly than `NumParticles`.
3. Convention : According to conventions too, it is better to use `.size()` as it is a property of the vector, instead of the variable `NumParticles`.
4. Performance: `.size()` is a **constant complexity** member function, so there is no significant performance difference between using a `const int` and `.size()`.

Answer (score 4):

I expect, given that the compiler (at least in this case) can inline all relevant code in the `std::vector`, it will be identical code [aside from 1000 being a true constant literal in the machine code, and `Bodies.size()` will be a "variable" value].

Short summary of findings:

- The compiler doesn't call a function for `size()` of a vector for every iteration, it calculates that in the beginning of the loop, and uses it as a "constant value".
- Actual code IN the loop is identical, only the preparation of the loop is different.
- As always: If performance is highly important, measure on your system with your data and your compiler. Otherwise, write the code that makes most sense for your design (I prefer using `for(auto i : vec)`, as that is easy and straight forward [and works for all the containers])

**Supporting evidence:**

After fetching coffee, I wrote this code:

```
class X
{
public:
    void Update() { x++; }
    operator int() { return x; }
private:
    int x = rand();
};

extern std::vector<X*> vec;
const size_t vec_size = 1000;

void Process1()
{
    for(auto i : vec)
    {
        i->Update();
    }
}

void Process2()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        vec[i]->Update();
    }
}


void Process3()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec_size; i++)
    {
        vec[i]->Update();
    }
}
```

(along with a `main` function that fills the array, and calls Process1(), Process2() and Process3() - the `main` is in an separate file to avoid the compiler deciding to inline everything and making it hard to tell what is what)

Here's the code generated by g++ 4.9.2:

```
0000000000401940 <_Z8Process1v>:
  401940:   48 8b 0d a1 18 20 00    mov    0x2018a1(%rip),%rcx        # 6031e8 <vec+0x8>
  401947:   48 8b 05 92 18 20 00    mov    0x201892(%rip),%rax        # 6031e0 <vec>
  40194e:   48 39 c1                cmp    %rax,%rcx
  401951:   74 14                   je     401967 <_Z8Process1v+0x27>
  401953:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  401958:   48 8b 10                mov    (%rax),%rdx
  40195b:   48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
  40195f:   83 02 01                addl   $0x1,(%rdx)
  401962:   48 39 c1                cmp    %rax,%rcx
  401965:   75 f1                   jne    401958 <_Z8Process1v+0x18>
  401967:   f3 c3                   repz retq 

0000000000401970 <_Z8Process2v>:
  401970:   48 8b 35 69 18 20 00    mov    0x201869(%rip),%rsi        # 6031e0 <vec>
  401977:   48 8b 0d 6a 18 20 00    mov    0x20186a(%rip),%rcx        # 6031e8 <vec+0x8>
  40197e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  401980:   48 29 f1                sub    %rsi,%rcx
  401983:   48 c1 f9 03             sar    $0x3,%rcx
  401987:   48 85 c9                test   %rcx,%rcx
  40198a:   74 14                   je     4019a0 <_Z8Process2v+0x30>
  40198c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  401990:   48 8b 14 c6             mov    (%rsi,%rax,8),%rdx
  401994:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
  401998:   83 02 01                addl   $0x1,(%rdx)
  40199b:   48 39 c8                cmp    %rcx,%rax
  40199e:   75 f0                   jne    401990 <_Z8Process2v+0x20>
  4019a0:   f3 c3                   repz retq 

00000000004019b0 <_Z8Process3v>:
  4019b0:   48 8b 05 29 18 20 00    mov    0x201829(%rip),%rax        # 6031e0 <vec>
  4019b7:   48 8d 88 40 1f 00 00    lea    0x1f40(%rax),%rcx
  4019be:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  4019c0:   48 8b 10                mov    (%rax),%rdx
  4019c3:   48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
  4019c7:   83 02 01                addl   $0x1,(%rdx)
  4019ca:   48 39 c8                cmp    %rcx,%rax
  4019cd:   75 f1                   jne    4019c0 <_Z8Process3v+0x10>
  4019cf:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Whilst the assembly code looks slightly different for each of those cases, in practice, I'd say you'd be hard pushed to measure the difference between those loops, and in fact, a run of `perf` on the code show that it's "the same time for all loops" [this is with 100000 elements and 100 calls to Process1, Process2 and Process3 in a loop, otherwise the time was dominated by `new X` in `main`]:

```
  31.29%  a.out    a.out                [.] Process1
  31.28%  a.out    a.out                [.] Process3
  31.13%  a.out    a.out                [.] Process2
```

Unless you think 1/10th of a percent is significant - and it may be for something that takes a week to run, but this is only a few tenths of a seconds [0.163 seconds on my machine], and probably more measurement error than anything else - and the shorter time is actually the one that in theory should be slowest, Process2, using `vec.size()`. I did another run with a higher loop count, and now the measurement for each of the loops is with 0.01% of each other - in other words identical in time spent.

Of course, if you look carefully, you will see that the actual loop content for all three variants is essentially identical, except for the early part of `Process3` which is simpler because the compiler knows that we will do at least one loop - `Process1` and `Process2` has to check for "is the vector empty" before the first iteration. This would make a difference for VERY short vector lengths.

Comment: Wow. Actually wow I am breath taken. When I posed this I expect either negative response for a "nooby" question, or no response at all. This work you have put into this answer is amazing. You sir deserve all the rep you have earnt

Answer (score 2):

I would vote for *for range*:

```
for (auto* body : Bodies)
{
    body->Update();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `body->Update();` insted of `Body->Update();`?

Answer (score 2):

`NumParticles` is not a property of the vector. It is some external constant relative to the vector. I would prefer to use the property `size()` of the vector. In this case the code is more safe and clear for the reader.

Usually using some constant instead of `size()` means for the reader that in general the constant can be unequal to the `size()`.

Thus if you want to say the reader that you are going to process all elements of the vector then it is better to use size(). Otherwise use the constant.

Of course there are exceptions from this implicit rule when the accent is put on the constant.  In this case it is better to use the constant. But it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this form:

```
for (auto const& it : Bodies)
{
    it->Update();
}
```